# iOS notification when app gets suspended

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

When the app enters background , I get notification `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` . Can I get almost the same notification when app gets `suspended`? So the app can work in background because of Bluetooth, because of CLLocationManager and so on, but sometimes it gets suspended. In that case I need to know about that, is there any notification like `UIApplicationDidEnterBackground` in that case?

Comment: How about https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622950-applicationwillresignactive ?

Comment: No, that is when the app resigns active.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The suspended state is not the same as the terminated state.  When your app is suspended it is still in memory but it is not currently executing.

Since it isn't executing any code, it isn't possible for you to get a notification when your app is suspended.

Your app is suspended some time after it enters the background; either when you complete any work you start in `didEnterBackground` or complete any work you start as a result of being called in the background (e.g. BLE or location delegate invocations).

Comment: ok, thank you, I thought that may be there is notification WillBeSuspended

Comment: it isn't necessary since, effectively, you are in control of when your app is suspended; it is suspended when you finish all of your work in the background.  If you take too long to finish that work then iOS will terminate your app